# SqlDbType.Date SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sqlclient, sqldbtype

I have a property like this:

```
private SqlParameter DateOfBirthSqlParameter
{
    get
    {
        return new SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.Date)
            {
                Value = dateOfBirth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            };
    }
}
```

`dateOfBirth` is a `DataTime` C# type. I use this parameter to add to my SQL command, that look like this.

```
Select * From mytable Where dob_dt = @date
```

The problem is that doesn't work in SQL Server 2005. I got an exception:

> *System.ArgumentException: The version of SQL Server in use does not
>   support datatype 'date'*

This because SQL Server 2005 doesn't support `Date`, this is a feature of later version (SQL Server **2008**).

There are many solutions to this, for instance change `SqlDbType.Date` to `SqlDbType.DateTime`

I guess the reference `System.Data` is a version that provide all features supported for SQL Server 2008. Should I change it to something that only support 2005? that will help to discover other possible mismatches? What is the best way to handle this situation?

Thanks.

**Update: 8/31/2012**

In the example, I used date of birth but In my application I used something else such as purchase_dt or something like it (with the time on it). My first Select Statement was:

```
Select * From mytable Where Cast(purchase_dt as Date) = @date
```

and that was fine in my computer with SQL Server **2008** and in another PC with SQL Server **2005** also was fine and just throws an exception when it got to the select.

But, once I fixed that, with:

```
Select * From mytable Where Cast(DATEDIFF(dd, 0, purchase_dt) as DateTime) = @date
```

This broke the entire web application (in the other PC)... The problem was `SqlDbType.Date`. but Why it didn't break it before?

Comment: Since your database model specifies DateTime (or it wouldn't compile in 2005), just use SqlbType.DateTime as you already surmised.

Comment: just use DateTime since that is the one supported by Sql Server 2005. Also, change the select statement as follows "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATEDIFF(DD, purchase_dt, @date) = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Data type `DATE` is not supported on SQL Server 2005,
`DATE` type is supported form SQL Server 2008 version.
Instead you could use `datetime` or `smalldate`

Answer (score 0):

```
private SqlParameter DateOfBirthSqlParameter
{
    get
    {
        return new SqlParameter("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime)
            {
                Value = dateOfBirth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a comment of your code as well, just something about what you did and why.

Comment: instead of using SqlDBtype.Date i use DateTime